# UISearchResultsTableView doesn't appear when UISearchBar becomes active

Tags: ios, uisearchresultscontroller

I need my searchBar to display search results when searchbar's textfield becomes active. I use

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

call, but have no object to show UISearchResultsTableView at once.
It shows only when entering fist letter in search textfield.

Answer (score 3):

Logic of filtering out the search result should be added in

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

can be used to refresh the array objects when you start editing the search bar.

Comment: That's is not what is particularly needed. I need to display all available search results below when text field is empty just when it gets focus. What method should I call?

Comment: If the searchBar Text is nil or empty, the array assigned to the tableview should have all the results. If it is empty, that is when you get no results.

Comment: Array is not empty, it has all results, but it doesn't display it on the screen of iPhone.

Comment: It displays results only when I put first letter in the search textbox.

Comment: Does the table view show all the results before the searchBar is selected or before the focus is set on the searchBar

Comment: No, table view just loads the content but doesn't show it.

Comment: Then your datasource for the tableview must be missing. Check that or Check if the cell gets the proper data from the Array of search results

Comment: I've checked: xcode creates tableview (all methods like cellForRow and row- and header- count are called), but doesn't display it.

Comment: Try populating the tableview even before the searchBar is active

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

It will be executed on touch the textfield .